# ERROR LNK1104 - .`obj` file without any file name

Tags: c++, visual-c++, visual-studio-2012, linker-errors

I am trying to compile a project where i am getting this error. I am very new to c++ and dont know much about VC++. And the most irritating part is that the error does not mention a name to the `.obj` file!!! Here is the whole error [copied from `Error List`] :

> Error 1   error LNK1104: cannot open file '.\Debug\.obj' E:\7zsrc\CPP\7zip\Bundles\Format7zF\LINK    7z

To be more specific, I am compiling the `Format7zF` bundle included with 7z source version 9.22ß. I have already tried most of the solutions out there but most times either the the problem is different or the solution does not work.

Any help would be great!

Thanks

### Update

I just noticed [from the .log file] that at the end of the linker `Debug\\.obj` was added! Hope this explains the problem more!

### Update 2

I am attaching a copy of the project. You can examine the project by opening the solution from `[ExtractionPathOfTheArchive]\CPP\7zip\Bundles\Format7zF\` Directory. Hope someone can help.

[Link to Project Source("d.zip")](http://www.mediafire.com/?jxbwd5ss7w754ul)
I have just converted the source files from VC++6 to VC++12 and changed the Output File Path in linker to `inherit from...`, nothing else.

Comment: Thanks for the "-1"! May I know what is the problem with this question??

Comment: Well I think the probem is exactly that there is no name for the object file. Something is wrong with your build procedure. Can't really suggest what it might be with the information given however. Not really much alternative to understanding the tools you are using I'm afraid.

Comment: @john What more information can I give? Please suggest so that my problem gets solved quickly! I am hanging around VS for 2 days to solve this problem.

Comment: Links to what you downloaded and the documentation might help. Someone may be prepared to read them. Some description of the steps you've gone through so far as well. From a very, very brief look it looks as though 7zip have overly complex and brittle build procedures which are hard for a newbie to get to work. But that could just be me being prejudiced.

Comment: I have updated the question with the sources and the documention is in the "DOC" Directory. But in the DOC Dir there is nothing extra about the compilation, only info about the Bundles the files.

Comment: OK, well I suspect that the problem was introduced in the conversion process. I had a look at the original project and there's nothing unusual in it at all. But VC++6 to VC++12 is quite a jump to make, there have been substantial changes to VC++ build procedures in that time. I've known these conversions to go wrong before, when you did the conversion it should have produced a report describing any problem encountered. Looking at that might help. I did try converting the project to VC++9 and that went fine. I don't have any later versions of VC++ available I'm afraid.

Comment: You've seen the 7zip FAQ http://www.7-zip.org/faq.html ? There are some issues with the platform SDK, no idea if this applies to you or not.

Comment: @john I think i have to reinstall VS. then it should work I think! As you already stated that it worked with VC++9 then there is some problem with my VS version! BTW, Thanks for your help and time.

Comment: Ok! I would ask you another favor. Please [Download the 7zip 9.22ß Sources from Here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/sevenzip/files/7-Zip/9.22/7z922.tar.bz2/download), Convert this to VC++9 project, Upload it into some file sharing site and please give the link to me. I believe that if I convert the project first to VC++9 and then to VC++12 it would work and the problem will be solved. I browsed SO and got a question about migration problem form VC++6 to VC++10. So, as you got the build right, I think that the same is the problem in my case. Thanks!

Comment: I am asking you to download the original sources, so that the new project is clean. Thanks.

Comment: I'm sorry, I'm at work, my copy of VC++9 is licensed for my companies use. I don't think I should use it to help you out in that way. You could try downloading it for yourself, http://microsoft-visual-c-2008-express-edition1.software.informer.com/9.0/ (never used this site my self, just googled it)

Comment: ok! thanks I have already had started the download! I understand your situation. BTW, Thanks for your kind attention to my question.

Comment: @john It is working now! Just opened the project under VC++9 and then again under VC++12. Two other problems were also there but they are small fixes that i know about. BTW, Thanks for your support!

Answer (score 1):

It's Too late, but for records. :)

I had same problem, when I converted the 'QUAKE' project from VC6 to VS2010.

I solved it by changing setting of '.s' files (asm code file).

Check [Properties/Configuaration Properties/Custom Build Setup/General/Outputs]

and there are "$(InputName).obj" macro, then try to change it as "%(Filename).obj".